# changing css of a sim payment form

Tags: authorize.net

I am trying to get rid of the headers and order information. Also the logos for cisa and master cards. How would I do that. I read in the manual that you can pass the hidden field like this in header

```
<INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME="x_header_html_payment_form"
VALUE="<style type='text/css' media='all'>
TD{font-family: arial, verdana,trebuchet,helvetica,geneva,sans-serif;fontsize:11px;
color:#000000;margin-left:1px;}
INPUT{font-family:Arial,Verdana, Trebuchet,Helvetica,Geneva,sans-serif;fontsize:11px;color:
#000000;margin-left:1px;}</style>
```

problem is that when I pass that the css starts showing up in the header as well...so I am totally confused as to what do I need to do to get this working. Any help will be appreciated

[image]